# declare a value for a module dependency in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I would like to set a value for a dependant module of may app.
Please have a look at this code :

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp',['mymodule']);
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
mymodule.value('value','toto');
```

I have thought to config but I can not achieve this.

Comment: Why doesn't using `.value` work?

Comment: I would like to use it on mymodule and not myapp. Actually I would like to decalre a value for a dependency module of mymodule

Answer (score 0):

You can define `.value` or a `.constant` in the module by defining it inside the module:

```
angular.module('mymodule').value('value', 'toto');
```

Comment: I would like a third module to define a value for this module. Actually, mymodule is a custom component loaded via bower